# Codenameone- Crash Errors with NavigateToLocation

Tags: android, codenameone

I see following error log from crash reports on google play.I don't know what is triggering this issue. I'm using TrackLocation API and Google Maps NavigatetoLocation method to use the native mapping feature.  I don't find where this is creating issue with the App and App is crashing. Please let me know if any one face similar issue. Thanks

Error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3030)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)


    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at com.codename1.social.GoogleImpl.onCreate (GoogleImpl.java:375)
      at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.onCreate (AndroidNativeUtil.java:84)
      at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.onCreate (CodenameOneActivity.java:307)
      at com.xxxx.xxx.MainStub.onCreate (MainStub.java:53)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7183)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1220)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2908)
```

Code:

```
  public static boolean navigateToLocation(String location) {
            boolean flg = false;
            String url = "comgooglemaps://?q=" + Util.encodeUrl("");
            if (location != null) {
                url = "comgooglemaps://?q=" + Util.encodeUrl(location.replace(',', ' ')) + "&directionsmode=driving&zoom=16&views=traffic";
            }

            Boolean b = Display.getInstance().canExecute(url);
            if (b != null && b.booleanValue()) {
                Command googleMaps = new Command("Use Google Maps");
                Command appleMaps = new Command("Use Apple Maps");
                Command cancel = new Command("Cancel");
                ComponentGroup cmps = ComponentGroup.enclose(
                        new Button(appleMaps), new Button(googleMaps)
                );
                // allows us to resize the dialog properly
                final boolean[] reshow = new boolean[1];
                Dialog dlg = new Dialog(BoxLayout.y()) {
                    @Override
                    protected void sizeChanged(int w, int h) {
                        reshow[0] = true;
                        dispose();
                    }
                };
                dlg.setDialogUIID("Container");
                dlg.add(cmps).add(ComponentGroup.enclose(new Button(cancel)));
                Command result = dlg.showStretched(BorderLayout.SOUTH, true);
                if (result == googleMaps) {
                    if (reshow[0]) {
                        navigateToLocation(location);
                        return false;
                    }
                    Display.getInstance().execute(url);
                    flg = true;
                } else if (result == appleMaps) {
                    if (reshow[0]) {
                        navigateToLocation(location);
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (location == null) {
                        Location l = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getLastKnownLocation();
                        Display.getInstance().openNativeNavigationApp(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
                    } else {
                        Display.getInstance().openNativeNavigationApp(location.replace(',', ' '));
                    }
                    flg = true;
                }
            } else if (location == null) {
                Location l = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getLastKnownLocation();
                Display.getInstance().openNativeNavigationApp(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
            } else {
                Display.getInstance().openNativeNavigationApp(location.replace(',', ' '));
            }
            return flg;
        }
```

Comment: If this was a build done more than a couple of weeks ago this problem was fixed.